# ¿Cómo puedo saber la línea dónde está situada una palabra en php?

Tags: php, web

Me gustaría que me ayudaseis a obtener el número de la línea de una palabra concreta. O sea, si tengo un archivo txt con las siguientes palabras:

189-Pamplona

345-Gerona

677-Madrid

y el usuario busca la palabra Gerona que se le imprima la línea donde se encuentra la palabra Gerona. En este caso: 345-Gerona.

Agradecería vuestra respuesta.

Comment: prueba si te resuelve el problema , leyendo el archivo *.txt linea por linea, e introduciendo cada linea en un arreglo, luego cuando quieras hacer la búsqueda de la palabra, buscarías en las posiciones del arreglo. espero haberte ayudado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En unas pocas líneas podría resolverse así, utilizando las funciones `file`y `array_filter`:

```
<?php    
// Leer el contenido del archivo en un array:
$array = file('archivo.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

/*
Array
(
  [0] => 189-Pamplona
  [1] => 345-Gerona
  [2] => 677-Madrid
)
*/

// Valor a buscar:
$search = 'Gerona';

// Obtener todas las líneas que tengan alguna coincidencia:
$matches = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($search) { 
             return preg_match("/^.*$search.*\$/m", $var); 
           });

// Si se encontró algo, mostrarlo:
if (count($matches) > 0) {
  foreach ($matches as $line) {
    print $line;
  }
}

/*
Se muestra:
345-Gerona
*/
```

Cambiando la búsqueda:

```
$search = 'ona';
```

Se obtiene como resultado:

```
189-Pamplona
345-Gerona
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte sencillo y claro. Todo funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Ahora bien, si yo quiero que salgan las coincidencias una debajo de la otra, ¿cómo sería? Ya que ahora salen todas en una misma línea.

Comment: Lo más simple, agregando un salto de línea, así: `print $line . '<br>';`

Comment: Gracias, que estúpido de no entenderlo. Es que aún estoy aprendiendo php y no se que hacía la función que me habías proporcionado.

Answer (score 2):

Encontre el siguiente código por internet para leer el archivo, lo adapte para saber en que línea del archivo se encuentra la palabra a buscar:

```
<?php
//Nombre del archivo
$archivo = "tuArchivo.txt";
//Se abre el archivo
$file = fopen($archivo, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!"); 
//Auxiliar para las lineas del archivo
$i = 0;
//Palabra a buscar
$palabraBuscar = "Gerona";
//Se lee el archivo
while(!feof($file))
{ 
    /*Comparación del archivo y la palabra a buscar si es verdad 
    se almacena en la variable $linea*/
    if($palabraBuscar == fgets($file)){
        $linea = $i;
    }
    i++;
}
//Se cierra el archivo
fclose($file);
//Se imprime el resultado
echo "La línea en que se encuentra la palabra ".$palabraBuscar." es: ".$linea;
?>
```

Fuente del código:

> http://biolucas.com/como-leer-un-archivo-txt-linea-a-linea-en-php-fget/

Espero te pueda servir!!

Comment: Está bien, gracias, pero deberías modificar las variables i y poner $ delante.

Comment: Es un error de dedo, solo fue un ejemplo de como debedrias de hacerlo.. Si te sirvio marca la respuesta como aceptada..

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la linea completa podrias usar una expresion regular para la busqueda y todo lo que coincida con la busqueda sera impreso en pantalla:

```
<?php

//ruta a archivo con el texto
$file = 'http://gray-world.net/etc/passwd/googletut1.txt';

//palabra o string a buscar
$searchfor = 'date';

//Prevenir que el navegador parsee esto como  html
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

//obtener el contenido del archivo asumiendo que el archivo existe y es legible
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

//escapar caracteres speciales en la busqueda
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

//termina la expresion regular, para coincidir con toda la linea
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

//busca y almacena todas las coincidencias en $matches

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Coincidencias encontradas:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No se encontraron coincidencias";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta mencionas 2 posibles necesidades:

> obtener el **número de la línea** de una palabra concreta

y

> se le imprima **la línea donde se encuentra la palabra** Gerona. En este caso: 345-Gerona.

Si es lo primero, J. Castro te dio una buena respuesta.

Si es lo segundo, deberías utilizar la función  [file()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file.php) `$lineasArchivo = file("archivo.txt");`, `$lineasArchivo` entonces guardaría un array con las líneas del archivo abierto, por lo que habría que llamar el array con el número de la variable `$i` (suponiendo que se use un código similar al provisto por J. Castro) para obtener la cadena de texto de esa línea:

`$textoLinea = $lineasArchivo[i];`

**NOTA:** Las líneas contadas de esta forma empezarán desde el número 0, cosa que normalmente no hacemos cuando contamos, ya que empezamos a contar desde 1. Por lo que probablemente haya que sumarle 1 para mostrarlo al usuario.

Comment: No muestra nada: El código es el siguiente-->https://ghostbin.com/paste/pj8vb

Comment: Había cometido un error. Lógicamente de donde se tenía que obtener la línea era del array que se guardaba, no de la variable donde abre el archivo. `$textoLinea = $lineasArchivo[i];`

Comment: Igual hay posibilidad de que el código ese te de error. A lo mejor te convendría buscar la palabra directamente en el array en lugar de recorrer el archivo línea por línea. Ahí habría que tener en consideración un control de qué hacer en caso de no encontrar lo que se está buscando.